# How to prevent additonal line space in HTML

Tags: jasper-reports

I am exporting iReport designed template to HTML, when rendered in email as body, it shows additional line spaces as shown below

```
Option 1: Delivery in Evening (17:00-21:00).


Option 2: Delivery on Saturday.
```

How to prevent line spaces so it would seen like below

```
Option 1: Delivery in Evening (17:00-21:00).
Option 2: Delivery on Saturday.
```

This happens only when exported to HTML from Java. PDF export is fine.

Here is my JRXML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="PreAlert" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="591" leftMargin="2" rightMargin="2" topMargin="5" bottomMargin="5" isIgnorePagination="true" uuid="59a0a3f5-2869-4b8b-8aae-a29eb50ecc64">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="790" splitType="Prevent">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="7e37eeb2-c2c2-40cb-94f1-585663f21321" x="34" y="73" width="500" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Option 2: Delivery on Saturday]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="0533379c-19e6-47e0-8dcc-14cbb9d1798e" x="34" y="54" width="500" height="17" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="11" isBold="false" pdfEncoding="Identity-H"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Option 1: Delivery in Evening (17:00-21:00).]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement uuid="09813fb9-7535-47da-83df-10b5ca5d174b" positionType="Float" x="15" y="26" width="540" height="1"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: I've tried your sample with *iReport 5.2.0* - everything if fine.

Comment: Yes Alex, this is in 5.2.0 which you had sent link to download. Thanks for that. This additional line breaks only when report exported from JAVA code.

Comment: JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();   exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR, false); exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, false);    exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, destFile);
exporter.exportReport();

Comment: I've tried your template with *Java* code - everything if fine. I've used the *JasperReports API 5.1.0*.

Comment: @Alex K Oops, OMG, where is this going wrong on my side. When I generate the Output report to HTML file and embed the HTML as email body, when I opened the email, entire contents of the HTML has additional line break. Same thing, I do not see when exported within iReport. Appreciate any clue on this Version I am using is 5.2.0

Comment: Realized, the problem was only when using JAVAX mail. When I switched over to Apache Commons Email, BINGO. HTML looks exactly the same as what was generated off JASPER Export. Thanks Alex for your time and effort for your guidance.

Comment: You are welcome :)  You can post your solution as an answer to help others

Comment: Sorry, I am back to square one, even apache commons is also not helping as email body shows additional break.

Comment: HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();
  email.setHostName(smtpHost);
  email.setSmtpPort(465);
  email.setAuthentication(username, password);
  email.setSSLOnConnect(Boolean.TRUE);
  email.setFrom(username);
  email.setSubject("TestMail");
  email.setCharset(org.apache.commons.mail.EmailConstants.UTF_8);
  email.setHtmlMsg(FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("c:/temp/convert/8703211635_20130928231615.html"), "UTF-8"));
  email.addTo(username);

Comment: Maybe it is an issue of mailing application?

Comment: Posted my resolution below

Answer (score 0):

Try to set these checkboxes checked:

- Remove Line When Blank
- Blank when null

in your iReport

Comment: Thanks Luri, No luck still the same. BTW, I am using SansSerif as the font.

Answer (score 0):

After long struggle and juggling, final culprit boiled down to *JRHtmlExporter* exporter

if I use following code to export to html, there are additional line breaks

```java
JRHtmlExporter exporter = new JRHtmlExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_OUTPUT_IMAGES_TO_DIR, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_USING_IMAGES_TO_ALIGN, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.FRAMES_AS_NESTED_TABLES, Boolean.FALSE);
exporter.setParameter(JRHtmlExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, destFile);

exporter.exportReport();
```

however when I used direct export, it is working. Not sure why behavior could be different

```java
String htmlFile = JasperExportManager.exportReportToHtmlFile(jrPrintFile);
```

and If I send this htmlFile contents over email body, there is no additional line breaks.
 Big question is why and I have long home work on this.

Comment: I have the same problem however I'm using JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfFile to export the file.Any suggestions?Thanks

Comment: @Lori You can use JasperExportManager as shown below, this works `/**
    * Fill Report
    */
   String jrPrintFile = "C:/temp/report.jrprint";
   JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(
     "C:/temp/report.jasper",
      jrPrintFile,
      jasperParams,
      new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(beanCollection));
   
   JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jrPrintFile, ""C:/temp/report.pdf");`